# Adding Migrations to Source Control and Merging Conflicting Migrations in Django

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I took over a Django project and discovered that migrations for various apps were not being tracked by Git. That seemed a bit problematic since my understanding was that one should always track the migrations. Is that pretty much the consensus or are there reasons not to do it?

The second part of the question has to do with the fact that I have done some work involving tweaking some migrations locally. I would now like to push the changes to production. However, I am unsure as to what the best way to combine the possible conflicts would be.

For instance, in production, I have the following:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    mysite/aldryn_forms/migrations/0019_auto_20200730_1455.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0016_auto_20200624_2028.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0016_auto_20200625_1125.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0017_merge_20200625_1129.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0018_auto_20200720_1743.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0005_auto_20200624_2028.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0005_auto_20200625_1125.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0006_merge_20200625_1129.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0007_auto_20200720_1743.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0008_paymentmodel_course.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0009_paymentmodel_user.py
    mysite/apps/plugins/migrations/0016_auto_20200624_2028.py
    mysite/apps/plugins/migrations/0016_auto_20200625_1125.py
    mysite/apps/plugins/migrations/0017_merge_20200625_1129.py
    mysite/apps/xyz/migrations/0005_auto_20200730_1455.py
```

Locally, I have the following:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    mysite/aldryn_forms/migrations/0019_auto_20201108_1623.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0016_auto_20201108_1623.py
    mysite/apps/common/migrations/0017_auto_20201108_1806.py
    mysite/apps/payment/migrations/0005_auto_20201108_1623.py
    mysite/apps/plugins/migrations/0016_auto_20201108_1623.py
    mysite/apps/xyz/migrations/0005_auto_20201108_1623.py
```

These are the files with custom work:

```
mysite/apps/common/migrations/0016_auto_20201108_1623.py
mysite/apps/common/migrations/0017_auto_20201108_1806.py
```

It appears that all the migrations existing on the production server have been applied to the production database. Hence, I have concluded that they correctly describe the state of the production DB.

What should I do to sync my local work with that currently in-production?

Answer (score 2):

First I would review code for conflicts in your new migrations and migrations aplied in production.

Then backup evrything (your site and production).

if you don't finde logic errors, try copy migrations files from production to yours site and go with :

```
python manage.py makemigrations –merge
python manage.py migrate
```

if it works then it will propably work in production.
There is article about it :
[https://www.algotech.solutions/blog/python/django-migrations-and-how-to-manage-conflicts/#:~:text=So%2C%20in%20order%20to%20allow,manage.py%20makemigrations%20%E2%80%93merge](https://www.algotech.solutions/blog/python/django-migrations-and-how-to-manage-conflicts/#:%7E:text=So%2C%20in%20order%20to%20allow,manage.py%20makemigrations%20%E2%80%93merge))

once i had it too.. annoing is that you will have to do this -merge evry new migration.
At some point I reset migrations.

When you will have database in order. You can do:

- backup db and remove insert from db table : migrations
- delete all migration files from porject dir
- qoute all paterns in urls.py
- go with makemigrations and migrate
- populete new db with old data (exept migration table)

oh there is even simpler method with --fake:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

that will put you with initial migration.